# setText crashes app when trying to display byte values

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a android app that send and recieves data. In the app i have a button an a few texviews. When i press the button then data (two chars) will be send. And an the data that has been send will be shown in two tekst views.

I did the same with two integers and that worked now i want to do the same with bytes and chars and that failes.

The logcat gives the following error:
10-28 09:27:19.338: E/AndroidRuntime(13138): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0

Beloww is the onClick lisener code:

```
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
                 
   // Control value
   ArrayOutput[0] = 'B';
   ArrayOutput[1] = 'B';

                                                
 //Creating TextView Variable
 TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
                 
 //Creating TextView Variable
TextView statustext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
                 
                 
       //Sets the new text to TextView (runtime click event)
 text.setText("You Have click the button");

                
// Convert string to bytes
ArrayOutput[0] = ArrayRecieved[0];
ArrayOutput[1] = ArrayRecieved[1];
                
 final char Byte1 = (char) ArrayOutput[0];
 final char Byte2 = (char) ArrayOutput[1];
                
final TextView Xtext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xtext);              
final TextView Ytext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ytext);
Ytext.setText(Byte1);
Xtext.setText(Byte2);
                
                     
 try
 {
   statustext.setText("Sending....");
   server.send(ArrayOutput);
         statustext.setText("Sending succes");
 } 
       catch (IOException e)
 {
      statustext.setText("Sending failed");
      Log.e("microbridge", "problem sending TCP message", e);
 }  
    }
 });
```

Does anybody have a sugestion what the problem might be? Any suggestions is welcome! if i need to supply more information please say so.

## Update

Thanks you all for your suggestions! For the onclick function it works! I tried to do the same for the recieve function. This event handler funnction is called when there is data avalable.

When i use the setText function it crashes my ap after a few cycles, in this function i have three settext operations. only the first one is called (then the app crashes). When i change the ordere of these operations then still only the first one is called. Could it be that the app displays the first settext operation but crashes? I use dummy data, so when the eventhandler function is called the actual recieved data is not used, but still the app crashes after the first operation. Does anybody have a sugestion?

On the other side data is send every second.

Below is the onRecieve (event handler)function:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(com.example.communicationmodulebase.Client client, byte[] data)
{
                
    Log.e(TAG, "In handler!");
                
    //Control value
    ArrayRecieved[0] = 'C';
    ArrayRecieved[1] = 'B';

    if (data.length < 2){
        return;
    }
                
   // Set data that has been recieved in array
   //ArrayRecieved[0] = data[0];
   //ArrayRecieved[1] = data[1];
                
   char Byte1 = (char) ArrayRecieved[0] ;
   char Byte2 = (char) ArrayRecieved[1] ;
                
   TextView Xtext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xtext);                 
   TextView Ytext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ytext);
   Xtext.setText(""+Byte2);
   Ytext.setText(""+Byte1);

   TextView textRecvStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.RecvStatusText);
   textRecvStatus.setText("In handler!");
                                    
   }
```

});

Comment: I have updated my post with my recieve function. When i comment all the settext operations out then the app doens't crash. Thank you for the ansewers on my send code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextView has two methods like

```
TextView.setText(CharSequence) and TextView.setText(int).
```

1) first method directly assigns a text to TextView which is passed as CharSequence (can be String,StringBuffer,Spannable...) 
2) second methods searches for the String resource that you define in Resources with ID passed as parameter.

and you are passing `char` as parameter. this `char` is type casted into `int` and invokes it as `TextView.setText(int)` and searches for the Resource String with that `int` ID whose value is not defined in Resources.

type cast `char` as `String` like `String.valueOf(char)` and try once...

Comment: Thank you for your reply! For sending data it works! Only in the recieve function it doesn't work. It only displays the one setText operation and then chrashes(?). I have updated my code. Could u take a look?

Comment: I can;t readout the Catlog because the USB is connected to a USB host controller on a Arduino. Is there a way to find out what the error might be? I'm guessing that is is the following error: The logcat gives the following error: 10-28 09:27:19.338: E/AndroidRuntime(13138): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0

Comment: may be you are doing the same mistake again. some where typecasting char into int

Answer (score 1):

The signature for the method you are using takes a CharSequence, hence  sequence of characters. Using `setText(someEmptyString + Byte1)`, you create a sequence of characters from the concatenation of someEmptyString (which you would define as "") and Byte1.

Answer (score 0):

set with some change like

```
 Ytext.setText(""+Byte1);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion for the send opertion it works only for the recieve operation(i have updated my post) the app crashes after the first setText operation.

Comment: check Byte2 is null or not

Comment: Hi, byte is filled at the line: char Byte2 = (char) ArrayRecieved[1] ; and the array is filled at : ArrayRecieved[1] = 'B';

Answer (score 0):

`setText()` expects string or resource id (int). If you want to display numeric value, you need to convert it to string, i.e.:

```
setText(String.valueOf(someInt));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out as below:

```
Ytext.setText(""+Byte1);
Xtext.setText(""+Byte2);
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, the suggestion workst for the send function. I tried to use the same for the recieve function but it fails after one setText operation. I have updated my code in my post. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Roy08 What is crash ? Also post crash .

Comment: The app totaly crashes, i can't show you the catlog data because the android Phone is connected via USB to a Arduino with USB host controller. When i comment the setText operations out of the onRecieve function then the app doesn't crash.